# Stop Carrierwave from Caching Storage Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, caching, carrierwave

Carrierwave is caching Azure storage information and uploading files to the wrong containers.

For example, if I upload an image to container "a" then I try to upload an image to container "b", it will still upload to container "a". I assume Carrierwave is caching the storage information somewhere instead of setting the container information each upload. How do I stop it from doing this?

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

storage :azure

def initialize(*)
super
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.azure_storage_account_name = account_name
    config.azure_storage_access_key = storage_key
    config.azure_container = model.container_name
  end
end
```

I also tried re-initializing the uploader for each upload but I still have the same problem.

```
uploader = FileUploader.new
uploader.store!(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of assigning config attributes to CarrierWave assign them to the initialized uploader object.

```
def initialize(*)
  super
  self.azure_storage_account_name = account_name
  self.azure_storage_access_key = storage_key
  self.azure_container = model.container_name
end
```